# Colored box for theorem with ntheorem

Tags: color, ntheorem

I would like to have every theorem with the same style to have the same colored box and to be able to configure the color. Like this :
[image]

I tried to use the package ntheorem with the option framed and to call the package framed but LaTeX returned the following errors :

```
! Undefined control sequence.\att@framecommand ->\psframebox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linecolor=red] \begin{att}
```

Compiled with the following code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}


\usepackage{etoolbox} %Pour la forme des démonstrations
\usepackage{fancybox,lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed} % Pour les fonds colorés
\usepackage{pifont} % Pour les symboles !
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} % Pour la couleur !


\begin{document}

{
    \shadecolor{red}
    \theoremstyle{break}
    \theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\bfseries}
    \theorembodyfont{\sffamily}
    \newshadedtheorem{att}{\danger Attention !}

}

\begin{att}
\lipsum[1]
\end{att}


\end{document}
```

My try for the package tcolorbox give this result :

[image]

the following error :

```
! Undefined control sequence.\kvtcb@fonttitle ->\sffamily \bfserie L
```

With this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}


\usepackage{etoolbox} %Pour la forme des démonstrations
\usepackage{fancybox,lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed} % Pour les fonds colorés
\usepackage{pifont} % Pour les symboles !
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} % Pour la couleur !



\begin{document}

\newtcbtheorem
{att}{\danger Attention !}
%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=
\sffamily\bfserie
}{th} 

\begin{att*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulumut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Namarcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\end{att*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You might have a look into the documentation of `tcolorbox` and its `theorem` library?

Comment: Sure ! I take a look !

Comment: Done ! I give it a try.

Comment: Errors poorfully !

Comment: You have written `\bfserie`, the command is `\bfseries` ;-) Correcting that, it should run... You are misusing the environment in my point of view

Comment: \newtcbtheorem{att}{\danger Attention !}{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=
{\sffamily\bfseries}}{th}%

Comment: `\begin{att*}{}{}` for example, otherwise the next free tokens are considered as first and 2nd arguments to the environment

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! You should write an answer as if I could check it for the post.

Comment: No, just check it and then provide a self-answer ;-) I have not done much to this

Comment: Yet, it still produce the "L" after the "!"

Comment: Did you use `\begin{att*}{}{}` as I proposed?

Comment: Now, yes and it doesn't do it thanks. Sorry I really didn't understood the way the package works...

Comment: I will post my version, but I do not mean to keep as an answer. I hope, you have a reasonably fresh TexLive or whatever distribution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}


\usepackage{etoolbox} %Pour la forme des démonstrations
\usepackage{fancybox,lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed} % Pour les fonds colorés
\usepackage{pifont} % Pour les symboles !
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} % Pour la couleur !




\begin{document}

\newtcbtheorem{att}{\danger Attention !}{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=
{\sffamily\bfseries}}{th}%

\begin{att*}{}{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulumut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Namarcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\end{att*}


\end{document}
```

[image]